The emphasis on inaction in the Hindu texts
This is something that is extremely emphasized in various religions all over the Eurasian continent and Hinduism is no exception. I've found quite a few passages about this subject and have put them in a list on a PDF file which I will share in the future, but I've only read a relatively few Hindu books because they are very big. If there are more passages about inaction, or nonmovement, to add I would really want to know about them.
https://vedabase.io/en/library/bg/4/18/#:~:text=One%20who%20sees%20inaction%20in%20action%20and%20action%20in%20inaction

One who sees inaction in action, and action in inaction, is
intelligent among men, and he is in the transcendental position,
although engaged in all sorts of activities.

These ones are from this book https://ebooks.iskcondesiretree.com/pdf/00_-_Srila_Prabhupada/Bhagavad_Gita/Bhagavad_Gita_As_It_Is.pdf

He is everlasting, present everywhere, unchangeable, immovable and
eternally the same.
Abandoning all attachment to the result of his activities, ever
satisfied and independent, he performs no fruitive action, although
engaged in all kinds of undertaking.
When the embodied living being controls his nature and mentally
renounces all actions, he resides happily in the city of nine gates
[the material body], neither working nor causing work to be done.
Understand that as the mighty wind, blowing everywhere, rests always
in the sky, all created beings rest in Me.
This material nature, which is one of My energies, is working under My
direction, O son of Kunté, producing all moving and nonmoving beings.
Under its rule this manifestation is created and annihilated again and
again.
I am the goal, the sustainer, the master, the witness, the abode, the
refuge, and the most dear friend. I am the creation and the
annihilation, the basis of everything, the resting place and the
eternal seed.
Furthermore, O Arjuna, I am the generating seed of all existences.
There is no being—moving or nonmoving—that can exist without Me.
O Arjuna, whatever you wish to see, behold at once in this body of
Mine! This universal form can show you whatever you now desire to see
and whatever you may want to see in the future. Everything—moving and
nonmoving—is here completely, in one place
You are the supreme primal objective. You are the ultimate resting
place of all this universe. You are inexhaustible, and You are the
oldest. You are the maintainer of the eternal religion, the
Personality of Godhead. This is my opinion.
You are the father of this complete cosmic manifestation, of the
moving and the nonmoving.
But those who fully worship the unmanifested, that which lies beyond
the perception of the senses, the all-pervading, inconceivable,
unchanging, fixed and immovable—the impersonal conception of the
Absolute Truth—by controlling the various senses and being equally
disposed to everyone, such persons, engaged in the welfare of all, at
last achieve Me.
The Supreme Truth exists outside and inside of all living beings, the
moving and the nonmoving. Because He is subtle, He is beyond the power
of the material senses to see or to know. Although far, far away, He
is also near to all
O chief of the Bhäratas, know that whatever you see in existence, both
the moving and the nonmoving, is only a combination of the field of
activities and the knower of the field.
One who can see that all activities are performed by the body, which
is created of material nature, and sees that the self does nothing,
actually sees.

http://www.vedanta-nl.org/ISHA.pdf

The Self is one and unmoving, swifter than the mind: the devas (the
senses) cannot overtake It as It darts before them. Remaining
motionless It passes the running ones.
It moves and moves not. Far away, It is near. Within all, it is yet
outside.

https://www.webpages.uidaho.edu/~rfrey/PDF/116/Upanishads116.pdf#:~:text=The%20senses%20cannot%20reachIt%2C%20for%20It%20moves%20ever,all%20this%20and%20It%20is%20outside%20all%20this.

When the five instruments (senses) of knowledge stand still, together
with the mind and when the intellect does not move, that is called the
Supreme State

https://www.esamskriti.com/e/Spirituality/Upanishads-Commentary/Book-Of-Wisdom-~-Isha-Upanishad-8.aspx

Brahman, though immobile and changeless, is described as “faster than
the mind” and “superseding others who are running” because It is
pre-existent everywhere, or in other words omnipresent at all
pervading.
That Brahman gives mobility to all, but is never caught in motion.
Whether objects in the world are in motion derive their mobility from
the power and brilliance of Brahman. Brahman, the centre on which
everything else moves, is itself not in motion. Through Brahman’s will
acting in the causal sphere, both the subtle and the gross, both
energy and the grosser from of energy called matter, are moved.

https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/3/verse/24

If I ceased to perform prescribed actions, all these worlds would
perish. I would be responsible for the pandemonium that would prevail,
and would thereby destroy the peace of the human race.


Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange! I see you are talking about inaction but can you tell what is your exact question?
